# Nested xml file to xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt

i have an xml file and wanted to transform into xsl file
Structure of the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Product>
    <Category>
      <a1>A</a1>
      <b1>B</b1>
      <c1>C</c1>
      <d1>
           <dd1>DD1</dd1>
           <dd1>DD2</dd1>
      </d1>
      <e1>E</e1>
     </Category>
     <Category>
      <a1>AA</a1>
      <b1>BB</b1>
      <c1>CC</c1>
      <d1>
           <dd1>DD3</dd1>
      </d1>
      <e1>EE</e1>
    </Category>
</Product>
```

Here in the first Category/d1 there are multiple records
i wanted the xsl file to be generated in this desired output

```
<table>
<th>a1</th>
<th>b1</th>
<th>c1</th>
<th>dd1</th>
<th>e1</th>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>C</td>
<td>DD1</td>
<td>E</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>C</td>
<td>DD2</td>
<td>E</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AA</td>
<td>BB</td>
<td>CC</td>
<td>DD3</td>
<td>EE</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i have tried out with this xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Product Information</h2>

  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>A1</th>
      <th>B1</th>
      <th>C1</th>
      <th>D1</th>
      <th>E1</th>

    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Product/Category">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="a1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="b1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="c1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="d1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="e1"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But i am getting concatenated multiple values at "d1"

can someone help to get output
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need a new row for each **dd1** element, therefore you need a nested **xsl:for-each** loop within your current loop, to get the **dd1** elements

```
<xsl:for-each select="d1/dd1">
```

You would need to make a tweak in how you get the **a1**, **b1**, **c1** and **e1** elements though, as you will no longer be positioned on the **Category** element. You would have to do this, for example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../a1"/>
```

Alternatively, you could define a variable to point to the **Category** element, and use that. Try this XSLT as an example

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Product Information</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>A1</th>
      <th>B1</th>
      <th>C1</th>
      <th>D1</th>
      <th>E1</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Product/Category">
      <xsl:variable name="Category" select="." />
      <xsl:for-each select="d1/dd1">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Category/a1"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Category/b1"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Category/c1"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Category/e1"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```